# Apply read Access permission for all child of a Parent in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, parent-child, access-rights

I have 30 Items inside Home Page in Sitecore . I want to give read accees-permission to all Child of Home except of home page.

There is any  way that i can apply Security editor in Home and Its apply to all child Items except Parent (Home).

I tried to use inheritance property but ITS RESTRICTING home page also.

Comment: Are you trying to remove read access for visitors of the site or content editors in the back end?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to deny read access to the children of the homepage.

You can select the homepage in the Content Editor, then press the `Assign` button in the `Security` tab. You can then select the `Everyone` or other specific role and disable Inheritance on `Descendants`.

This means that read access is removed on all Descendants, not just children. Selecting this option for descendants does not affect the homepage itself.